# sql query ascending or descending order

Tags: php, sql

In my project I want to one query which is perform kms wise ASC|DESC query

My Query Is:

```
select p_kms from Places where place_type='1' ORDER BY p_kms DESC
```

My Out is :

```
p_kms
81
71
70
602
52
493
272
245
2049
1968
1948
1852
1813
1811
1807
1771
1758
174
1737
125
125
123
107
1035
```

Please let me know what I can do to solve this query.
I use both ways `ASC` and `DESC` but not getting a satisfying result. 
How can I display `p_KMS` in `ASC` | `DESC` `mode(ORDER BY p_KMS ASC|DESC)` 
When you create an index on a column or number of columns in MS SQL Server (I'm using version 2005), you can specify that the index on each column be either ascending or descending. I'm having a hard time understanding why this choice is even here. Using binary sort techniques, wouldn't a lookup be just as fast either way? What difference does it make which order I choose?

Comment: Please provide more info about you `Places` table schema

Comment: what is the data type set for that column. if it is varchar change it to INT

Comment: what is the data type of p_kms ?

Comment: Show your table structure

Comment: maye you should ask the second part of your question as a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
ORDER BY p_kms * 1 DESC
```

will convert it to a number since it seems to be a text value. Or use

```
ORDER_BY cast(p_kms as unsigned) DESC
```

Check the table definition and change it. You can change the data type to int like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN p_kms int;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `p_kms` is a varchar. So you would have to cast it to a number when ordering:

```
select p_kms from Places where place_type='1' ORDER BY cast(p_kms as unsigned) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is right, But you want to change field "p_kms" as integer,

```
ALTER TABLE  Places MODIFY COLUMN p_kms int;
```

Hope u got it :) Enjoy :)